# 'Embed Objects In' menu items are all disabled. How to enable?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm following the instructions for creating a ScrollView in the book 'Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X, 3rd Edition'. I'm using Xcode 3.2.3.

I've already created a view, into which I've drawn shapes and lines.

The next task is to convert this to a NSScrollView, which according to the book should be a simple case of selecting the existing view and choosing Layout -> Embed Objects In -> Scroll View.

However whatever object I select, the items in the 'Embed Objects In' menu are all disabled.

How can I enable the Embed Objects In -> Scroll View item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The important thing here is not to try selecting the view in the MainMenu.xib window. Select the view in the actual document window and make sure the resize handles are visible. A little fiddly, but once you get the right object selected, then the embed objects menu items become enabled.

Comment: Actually I'm talking complete rubbish here. *Double click* on the 'StretchView' object in the MainMenu.xib window will highlight the view in the document window.